# How can I deserialize a complex XML element with no values to null?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

```
<Customer>
<FirstName>SomeValue</FirstName>
<LastName>Somevalue</LastName>
<Address/>
</Customer>
```

I have the above xml,  Address element is a complex object. When I am trying to deserialize to C# object, all the properties in the address object is set to null, but my requirement is to set the address object it self to null. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the c# for your `Customer` and `Address` classes?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

To confirm your question, you are asking: **When deserializing XML, can I map an empty element to a `null` property value, but map a non-empty element to a non-`null` property value?**

Assuming you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), this is not implemented out of the box.  `XmlSerializer` will only map an element to a `null` value when the attribute [`{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}nil`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil), usually abbreviated `xsi:nil`, has value `"true"`.  From [Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx):

> The XmlSerializer class equates a true value for the **nil** attribute with a null reference, performing the following run-time conversions:
>
> - When deserializing an XML document into objects: If the XmlSerializer class encounters an XML element that specifies xsi:nil="true", it assigns a null reference (if applicable) to the corresponding object.
> - When serializing objects into an XML document: If the XmlSerializer class encounters a null reference for an object corresponding to an XML element, it either generates an element that specifies xsi:nil="true" or leaves the element out entirely, depending on whether a nillable="true" setting applies.

Since `xsi:nil` is not present in your empty `<Address>` element, it will not get mapped to `null` automatically.

As a workaround, you could introduce an extra "proxy" property for `Address` into `Customer` that, during deserialization, checks to see if the `Address` being set has default values, and if so, sets the underlying address value to `null`.  For instance, if your classes look like:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

You could do this in a couple ways:

1. With reflection.  Introduce the following extension methods:

   ```
   public static class ObjectExtensions
   {
       public static IEnumerable<object> Members(this object obj)
       {
           if (obj == null)
               return new object[0];
           var type = obj.GetType();
           return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod(true) != null && p.CanRead)
               .Select(p => p.GetValue(obj, new object[0]))
               .Concat(type.GetFields().Select(f => f.GetValue(obj)));
       }

       public static bool IsDefault(this object obj)
       {
           if (obj == null)
               return true;
           var type = obj.GetType();
           if (type.IsValueType)
           {
               return obj.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(type, true));
           }
           return false;
       }

       public static bool MembersAreDefault(this object obj)
       {
           return obj.Members().All(v => v.IsDefault());
       }
   }
   ```

   Then modify `Customer` as follows:

   ```
   public class Customer
   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }

       public string LastName { get; set; }

       [XmlIgnore]
       public Address Address { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("Address")]
       [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
       public Address SerializableAddress
       {
           get
           {
               return Address;
           }
           set
           {
               if (value != null && value.MembersAreDefault())
                   value = null;
               Address = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The property `SerializableAddress` checks using reflection to see whether the incoming `Address` has any non-default values.  If not, the underlying property is set to null.

   This solution is robust and reusable, but since it uses reflection, performance may not be great.
2. With a a standard interface to check whether any properties have been set in a given type.  First, introduce the following:

   ```
   public interface IHasDefaultMemberValues
   {
       bool MembersAreDefault();
   }
   ```

   Next, implement that interface for `Address`:

   ```
   public class Address : IHasDefaultMemberValues
   {
       // Properties as above.

       #region IHasDefaultMemberValues Members

       public virtual bool MembersAreDefault()
       {
           return Street1 == null && Street2 == null && City == null && State == null && Zip == null && Country == null;
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

   Finally, modify `Customer` identically to solution #1.

   This solution is performant, but depends upon `MembersAreDefault()` being correctly maintained when new properties are added to `Customer`.

Comment: Thanks DBC. But I have used regular expression to remove the empty nodes from the string, before Deserializing it and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the *XmlIgnore* attribute to exclude a property of your objects

```
[XmlIgnore] 
public Address {get; set;}
```